# 2 result perecentage with the same table

Tags: sqlite, group-by, subquery, percentage, case-when

```
select AGE,
(count (case when age > 22 then name end)*100.0/count(name)) as percentage
from student;
```

Result
20  30.0

```
select name, age,
(select 100*age/sum(age) over () as percentage from student) as percentage ,
(count(case when age > 22 then name end )*100.0/ count (name)) as Total_Perecentage 
from student
WHERE age > 22
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Result

```
Elis    27  9   100.0
Mice    23  9   100.0
Sara    25  9   100.0
```

My question How can I update the Total_percentage from 100% to 30% ( all result in one table ) as the first query

In simple words, I need to say the 30% is the total percentage of 3 names who above 22 of all 10 students.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10TGB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier with a subquery that aggregates conditionally on the table:

```
SELECT name, age, 
       (SELECT 100 * AVG(age > 22) FROM student) AS Total_Perecentage 
FROM student 
WHERE age > 22
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b0e096e0d58fc2e2d8ae4666f58cd981).
Results:

> | name | age | Total_Perecentage |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Sara | 25 | 30 |
> | Mice | 23 | 30 |
> | Elis | 27 | 30 |